# Nearest places from a certain point

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have the following table

```
create table places(lat_lng point, place_name varchar(50));

insert into places values (POINT(-126.4, 45.32), 'Food Bar');
```

What should be the query to get all places close to particular lat/long?

gis is installed.

Answer (score 10):

```
select *
from places
where lat_lng <-> POINT(-125.4, 46.32) < 1
order by lat_lng <-> POINT(-125.4, 46.32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working.

Could you please tell me, what is the use of `< 1` in this query.

Comment: The `< 1` is a cutoff for the minimum distance a place needs to be to get included in the result.

Answer (score 10):

If you actually wanted to use PostGIS:

```
create table places(
    lat_lng geography(Point,4326),
    place_name varchar(50)
);

-- Two ways to make a geography point
insert into places values (ST_MakePoint(-126.4, 45.32), 'Food Bar1');
insert into places values ('POINT(-126.4 45.32)', 'Food Bar2');

-- Spatial index
create index places_lat_lng_idx on places using gist(lat_lng);
```

Now to find all of the places within 1 km (or 1000 m):

```
select *, ST_Distance(lat_lng, ST_MakePoint(-126.4, 45.32)::geography)
from places
where ST_DWithin(lat_lng, ST_MakePoint(-126.4, 45.32)::geography, 1000)
order by ST_Distance(lat_lng, ST_MakePoint(-126.4, 45.32)::geography);
```

Comment: Do you know why we have to type cast `ST_MakePoint` to `geography`? I just faced an issue where ST_Distance was throwing wrong results when I didn't type cast it. ST_distance accepts geometry and ST_MakePoint already returns geometry. So what exactly happened there!?

Comment: ST_Distance on geometry types uses a Cartesian distance, which will be misleading if using distance units of degrees lng/lat. ST_Distance on geography types finds the minimum distance around WGS 84 spheroid, and returns a realistic distance in metres.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Indexing on a location field :

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name USING GIST(location);
```

GiST index is capable of optimizing “nearest-neighbor” search :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY location <-> point '(-74.013, 40.711)' LIMIT 10;
```

**Note:** The point first element is longitude and the second element is latitude.