# How to dispatch and auto-allocate requests to the nearest drivers

Tags: algorithm

First of all, I must say that I was very hesitant to post the following as I am afraid from getting down votes. However, I've spent days thinking about a solution and I haven't found one. My last hope is to get some answers in this post.

**The Problem**

Say that you have a large database of **drivers** connected in real-time to your backend, while you are fetching their lat/long each **5 seconds** and posting it back to the backend so you update in real-time a driver's location. Let's suppose that we want to benefit form drivers and their positions to let a particular user find the closer connected driver to it (like in UBER,Lyft, etc..).

**The question:**

How is it possible to dispatch request to these drivers ? (I want you to share with me only you thoughts and ideas).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is called "GeoSpatial search".

If you are looking for algorithms to implement then take a look at [Nearest Neighbour Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#k-nearest_neighbor)

The most famous algorithm is k-Nearest Neighbours algorithm.

If you are only interested in using an existing implementation and build your application on top of it then there are existing databases & search applications which provide capability of GeoSpatial search.

Check Apache Solr which provides Geospatial search capabilities. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search

you just need to feed your drivers live location into this and query with current location of user. Solr will take care of finding the nearest drivers and you will get a search result with your matching criteria.

You can use this as a starting point to build your app with location based searches. In pratice, Uber, Lyft and other major services have their own in-house application with custom implementations.

Comment: Could also consider the GIS functions in Postgres (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644988/nearest-places-from-a-certain-point) or the data structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree